# When are collections enumerated (IEnumerable)

Tags: c#, linq, collections, ienumerable, yield-return

Recently, I ran into a strange problem where I had a method generate an `IEnumerable` collection of objects. This method contained four `yield return` statements that returned four objects. I assigned the result to a variable `results` using the `var` keyword.

```
var result = GenerateCollection().ToList();
```

This effectively meant: `List<MyType> result = GenerateCollection()`.

I made a simple for loop over the elements of this collection. What surprised me is that the collection was reenumerated for each call to the list (for each `result[i]`). Later I used the `result` collection in a LINQ query which had some bad results performance-wise due to the continual reenumeration of the collection.

I solved the problem by casting to array instead of the list.

What this makes me wonder now is when are the collections enumerated? Which method calls make collections reenumerate?

EDIT: The `GenerateCollection()` method looked similarly to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyType> GenerateCollection()
{
    var array = data.AsParallel(); //data is a simple collection of sublists of strings
    yield return new MyType("a", array.Where(x => x.Sublist.Count(y => y == 'a') == 0));
    yield return new MyType("b", array.Where(x => x.Sublist.Count(y => y == 'b') == 0));
    yield return new MyType("c", array.Where(x => x.Sublist.Count(y => y == 'c') == 0));
    yield return new MyType("d", array.Where(x => x.Sublist.Count(y => y == 'd') == 0));
}
```

Comment: Please, show implementation of GenerateCollection method and your for each loop which reproduces problem

Comment: How `MyType` looks like? What it does with second parameter of constructor?

Comment: It basically is a tuple of a string and a list of strings.

Comment: As I've said probably a hundred times on SO: if I could tell people just one thing about LINQ it is that a query expression produces a *query* not *a result set*. You're making a sequence of questions, not a sequence of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are yielding objects which have queries inside - it's not some sequence of `array` values - its iterator objects which are not executed when you are passing them to constructor of `MyType`. When you create list of `MyType` objects

```
var result = GenerateCollection().ToList();
```

all `MyType` instances are yielded and saved into list, but if you haven't executed iterators in `MyType` constructor, then queries are not executed. And even more - they will be executed each time again, if you'll call some operator which executes query, e.g.

```
result[i].ArrayIterator.Count(); // first execution
foreach(var item in result[i].ArrayIterator) // second execution
    // ...
```

You can fix it if you'll pass result of query execution to `MyType` constructor:

```
yield return new MyType("a", array.Where(x => !x.Sublist.Contains('a')).ToList())
```

Now you are passing list of items instead of iterator (you can use `ToArray()`) also. Query is executed when you are yielding `MyType` instance, and it will not be executed again.

Comment: I would also consider whether it doesn't make more sense to move that `ToList()` inside the `MyType` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.Where(x => x.Sublist.Count(y => y == 'a') == 0)
```

This piece of code will be enumerated every time you access it in `MyType`. Use `ToList` or `ToArray` to ensure it is enumerated only once in place where the code is written.

Answer (score 1):

collections which are based on deferred execution gets enumerated as soon as you use them For-example IEnumerable,IQueryable etc. and collections which are based on immediate execution gets enumerated as soon as they are created for example LIST.